# Where is java.nio.file

Tags: java, import, nio

I am reading java documentation that tells me there should be a java.nio.file namespace. But when I attempt to import it the precompiler is complaining that it doesn't exist.

What's up?

Comment: Post the code you are using to import the package...maybe the problem is in that line.

Comment: java is a language not a framework btw.

Comment: "java" means many things

Comment: and the only point Java means framework is JMF, and this definitely was not about JMF.

Comment: @Woot4Moo: Wrong. There is a Java framework/platform (going by the names of Java Standard Edition, Java Enterprise Edition, and Java Mobile Edition), as well as the Java language. They have similar names, but are totally different concepts. :-D

Comment: Intriguing because J2EE is a specification, not a framework. J2SE and J2ME are not frameworks either they are specifications as far as I know.  In my years I have never heard anyone ask me to write a program using the Java framework, maybe they are just dumb?

Comment: People usually call it the Java platform. However, if you're coming from the .NET world where the word "framework" is usually used, you'll notice that they're more or less equivalent.

Comment: learn something new every day :)

Comment: Note that there is no Java precompiler. At least from the outside, the Java compiler acts as a single program.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`java.nio.file` is coming in Java 7. It's not in Java 6 or before.

You must be reading the [JDK7 docs](http://java.sun.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html).

Until then, you're stuck with the steaming heap of unpleasantness that is [java.io.File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: ahhh... so go get the new jdk.. gotcha. Thanks

Comment: Be careful, JDK7 is still a long way from final release. It does seem to be reasonably stable, though.

Comment: I was just noticing that. Looks like I have latest release. I'll just get the correct documentation.