# Get total size of file in bytes

Tags: java, fileinputstream

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java get file size efficiently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116574/java-get-file-size-efficiently)

I have a File called filename which is located in `E://file.txt`.

```
FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream(filename);
```

What I want to do is to calculate the size of this file in bytes. How can I have this done?

Comment: why do you want to do it with a fileinputstream?

Comment: This is not a duplicate answer. How to get a file size and how to get a file size efficiently are two different topics.

Comment: @JanBodnar you could nominate to reopen this question.

Comment: Done. I have't noticed that option.

Answer (score 305, accepted):

You can use the `length()` method on `File` which returns the size in bytes.

Comment: This is a perfect answer, and I know I have done a bunch of weird things to get this in the past to get the size of a file. Wish I knew about this a long time ago!

Answer (score 56):

You don't need FileInputStream to calculate file size, `new File(path_to_file).length()` is enough. Or, if you insist, use `fileinputstream.getChannel().size()`.

Comment: What does it return? `fileinputstream.getChannel().size()`

Comment: please refer to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#size()

Answer (score 8):

You can do that simple with [`Files.size(new File(filename).toPath())`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#size%28java.nio.file.Path%29).

Comment: In hindsight, needing both `Path` and `File` might be quite verbose, @Swapnil's answer might be more concise.

Comment: Yes but Java.nio.Files is defined for java 1.7+

Comment: Note that Java 1.6 has been end of life for a while. Even 1.7 is effectively eol as of April 2015. I don't think this being available in 1.7+ is a real issue.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2034427/where-is-java-nio-file

Comment: I'm writing this in 2015, and Java 1.6 is still used (and maintained!) in production where I work. Legacy systems are common in the real world...

Answer (score 7):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            System.out.println(file.length());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```